# MySQL/PHP: Cannot select from database but the element exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, mysqli

I know this has been asked a lot, but I can't seem to find the right answer for me. In PHPMyAdmin, the username "user" and password "test" exists--but for some reason it keeps saying it doesn't. The output of the code is:

Successfully connected to DB email:*user* password:*test* Username and Password does not Match

Here is the code:

```
$con = new mysqli('somewhere.com','admin','*****','nameofdb');
    if($con->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
    }
    else{
        echo "Successfully connected to DB ";
    }
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eml']);
       $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pwd']);
       //$encrPassword = md5($password);


       $login = $con->query("SELECT * 
                            FROM logininfo 
                            WHERE email = $email
                            AND password = $password");
       if($login == FALSE){
            echo " email:*$email* ";
            echo " password:*$password* ";
            //echo " password:*$encrPassword* ";

            echo "Username and Password does not Match";
       }
       else {
            echo "Hey this works";
       //Check if user is logged in, if not then redirect.     
            /*session_start();
            if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == FALSE){
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            }*/
            header("Location: ../browse/index.php");
       }
        mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the query variables have to have quotation marks around them?

SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somecol='$someVar' AND someothercol='$someothervar';

Answer (score 0):

There's an error on the query, it might be easier to debug if you echo the query and you test it on mysql, you can do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM logininfo 
          WHERE email = $email
          AND password = $password";
echo $query;
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

two simple steps
1..check out your database in phpmyadmin  that those username and password matches with your input username or password.if it is then echo query to know what's inside query.
2..if it is then make sure if you are using md5 encryption on signup if you are using then decrypt it on sign in like

```
$password=md5($password);
```

Comment: I was using md5 encryption, but then took it out to help the debugging process. Whenever I echo the query I get: DB SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = test AND password = test

Comment: with md5 password length in db shouldn't b too short,remove encryption in sign up and login both then try.

Comment: I removed all encryption. No luck. :|

Comment: $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eml']);
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pwd']);
   
   $query = "SELECT (email, password) 
    FROM users 
    WHERE email = $email
    AND password = $password";
   
   if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)){
     echo "Hey this works";

Comment: your query is wrong,remove brackets after select clause write like and use single quotes around email and password write this one "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'".use mysql_query() instead of mysqli_query()